# Android Tasker app looping script not looping

Tags: android

I'm using the Tasker app for Android and I'm having trouble getting a loop to work.  I was hoping someone could provide some insight, as a loop is a fairly simple programming concept.  I'm guessing that I'm just missing something specific to Tasker's syntax.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to write a script that plays a sound and vibrates in a loop 3 times.  I can get it to execute one time through, but it won't loop.

**What I've tried**

So far I have tried a few variations on both for and if loops, but I can't seem to get the loop part working.  The basic idea I'm trying is:

1. Create a counter and set it to 0
2. Open an if statement (I've also tried it as a for loop) with the condition that the counter is less than 3.
3. Within the loop, play a sound and perform a vibrate action.
4. Increment the counter by 1.
5. Goto the start of the loop again.

**How I'm trying it**

As I've mentioned, I've tried it a few different ways, but this is the most recent attempt:

```
1.  Variable Set
%Counter, 0

2.  If
%Counter < 3

    3. Notify Sound
    Sound

    4. Vibrate
    500

    5. Variable Add
    %Counter, 1

    6. Goto
    Action Number, 2

7.  End If
```

When I put a Flash in there, I can see that the counter does get incremented, but it ignores the Goto part.  Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

**Update and solution**

Based on the suggestion from Anthony Atkinson, I added a Wait after the sound/vibrate pieces run, and that got the loop working.  After some more research, it appears that I need to add a Notify Cancel near the end of the loop to clear things out.  I can see the icon being removed from the Notification area when it does so.

It looks like Tasker was seeing something already running and skipped over it when it looped.  If anyone has a better explanation of that, I'd appreciate hearing it.

In case anyone else is having the same problem I was, the updated (and working) script is as follows:

```
1.  Variable Set
%Counter, 0

2.  If
%Counter < 3

    3. Notify Sound
    Sound

    4. Vibrate
    500

    5. Variable Add
    %Counter, 1

    6. Wait
    0, 3, 0 ,0

    7.  Notify Cancel

    8. Goto
    Action Number, 2

9.  End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got started with tasker, but I've been an Android developer for a while. Most of the time these actions are asynchronous and you may actually be doing these all at the *same time* without giving the first round enough time to finish. In other words, this process might work if it were blocking, but it may be asynchronous. Maybe try adding in a sleep time after each round? Say, 750ms or something like that, and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried adding a 5 second wait between the counter increment and the Goto, and it partly helped.  It now loops three times, but only the vibrate repeats.  The sound only plays the first time through.  I'll try adding pauses in a few other places and see if that does anything.

Comment: How long is the notification sound?

Comment: It's less than a second, so it wouldn't be extending past the 5 second pause.  I added the pause in a few other places, but it's still only playing the sound once.

Comment: I found something that works, though it's a bit quirky.  If I add a Notify Cancel at the end of the loop, just before the Goto, it does the trick.  Best as I can tell, it looks like Tasker thinks the notification is still running/active, or something along those lines, so it doesn't run it again.  Thank you for your help on this, I'll mark your response as the answer to give you credit, since you did help me get the loop part working.  I'll also update my post to put the solution there.